# if(query1value = query2value) {} else {}

Tags: php, mysql, equals

So, I am wondering how I can compare the result of one query to the result of another query in a if-statement. Like this:

```
$team = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM team WHERE teamName='$teamName'");
$tplayer = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM player WHERE playerName='$playerName'");

if($team==$lplayer){
//Do something
}
else{
//Do something else
}
```

This does not work... Why?

Now, why doesnt this work:

```
$tleague = mysql_query("SELECT teamId from team
    WHERE leagueId=(SELECT leagueId FROM league WHERE leagueName='$leagueName')");
$tplayer = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM player WHERE playerName='$playerName'");

$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($tleague);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($tplayer);

if($row1['teamId']==$row2['teamId']){}
else{}
```

Comment: because you have a result resource.  You need to actually get the data from it with [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or similar.  Also, don't use `mysql_` functions anymore, they are deprecated. ^^

Comment: Please check update answer and let me know if there are problems

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` on the query, and compare the returned values. Something like the below. What you're comparing is the two returned resource objects:

```
$team = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM team WHERE teamName='$teamName'");
$tplayer = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM player WHERE playerName='$playerName'");
$t = mysql_fetch_assoc($team);
$p = mysql_fetch_assoc($tplayer);
if($t['teamId'] ==$p['teamId']){
//Do something
}
else{
//Do something else
}
```

**However, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` methods, instead look at using [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) // [Tutorial](http://codular.com/php-mysqli)**.

Answer (score 1):

You are not fetching any result from queries. Do something like

```
$team_result = mysql_fetch_array($team);
$tplayer_result = mysql_fetch_array($tplayer);
```

Then use fetched result to make your `if` condition

```
if($team_result['teamId'] == $tplayer_result['teamId'])
{
    //do something
}
```

Also please stop using `mysql` as it is deprecated, switch to `PDO` or `mysqli` for new projects

`Update`

The new query have mistake. Why don't you use a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
$tleague = mysql_query("SELECT a.`teamId` from `team` a LEFT JOIN `league` b ON a.`leagueId` = b.`leagueId` WHERE b.`leagueName` = '$leagueName'");
$tplayer = mysql_query("SELECT `teamId` FROM `player` WHERE `playerName`='$playerName'");

$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($tleague);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($tplayer);

if($row1['teamId']==$row2['teamId'])
{
// do something
}
else
{  
// do something else
}
```

`UPDATED AGAIN`

I merged all queries in one and i encapsuled data in the query `'".$playerName."'` and `'".$leagueName."'`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT a.`teamId` from `team` a LEFT JOIN `league` b ON a.`leagueId` = b.`leagueId` LEFT JOIN `player` c ON b.`teamId` = c.`teamId` WHERE b.`leagueName` = '".$leagueName."' and c.`playerName`= '".$playerName."'");
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo 'Found: ' . $row['teamId'];
}
else
{ 
    echo 'Not Found.';
}
```

Comment: This select get result in first query where leguename is = $leaguename, isn't it?

Comment: It should but something does not work. There are three tables. One called league, one called team and one called team. We only have leagueName as input and playerName. player-table is joint to team by teamid and team-table is joint to league by leagueid.

Comment: I merged all query in one to match you criteria, please have alook and tell if now is working

Comment: Still does not work: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Did you copy the entire updated again? I placed an if statment so it couldn't give error if not fetching

Comment: No :( Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Are you trying this query only or others? I really can't see the error

Answer (score 0):

do it like that

```
   $team = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM team WHERE teamName='$teamName'");
   $tplayer = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM player WHERE playerName='$playerName'");
   $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($team);
   $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($tplayer);

if($row1['teamId']==$row2['teamId']){
 //Do something
}
 else{
 //Do something else
}
```

**EDIT:**

on your second edit your problem is in the query itself .

try this one

```
    $tleague = mysql_query("SELECT t.teamId from team inner join league l On t.leagueId = l.leagueId  
 WHERE t.leagueName='".$leagueName."' ");
```

Comment: i know why :) , because you should use PDO or mysqli :) instead of mysql

Comment: and also escape your variables `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent sql injection :)

Comment: True, but it shouldn't affect that vote on the answer.  To make it in PDO, you'd have to make a full tutorial.  EDIT: I misread and assumed it was checking ID's, but still...

Comment: any way good it solved your issue :) , good luck with the rest

Comment: @echo_me Hi again, could you please look at my updated version? I just dont understand what my problem is in this one

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given i

Comment: try updated answer , the query is nice i dont know what are you doing , your code changes everytime . can you be honest and show your real code ?so i can understand

Comment: i tried updated answer. i am being honest. why would i lie? it didnt work. this is my error message:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Comment: well! mysql_num_rows() i didnt say it in my answer nor in your answer, so this its out of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work, because it's not the result of the query. You need to pass to a variable the mysql_result i.e.:

```
$result1 = mysql_result($team, 0);
$result2 = mysql_result($tplayer, 0);
if ($result == $result2) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$teamQuery = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM team WHERE teamName='$teamName'");
$lplayerQuery = mysql_query("SELECT teamId FROM player WHERE playerName='$playerName'");

$team = mysql_fetch_assoc($teamQuery);
$lplayer = mysql_fetch_assoc($lplayerQuery);

if($team['teamId']==$lplayer['teamId']){
//Do something
}
else{
//Do something else
}
```